# Read a Text File in Windows 8

Tags: c#, windows, windows-8

I'm having some trouble reading an embedded resource (text file) in [windows-8](/questions/tagged/windows-8), usually I use `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` but I can't seem to do it in this one. I'm referencing the System.Reflection namespace but it says cannot find, thinking it was possibly removed.

Any ideas?

Currently using Windows 8 Consumer Preview

Code:
`Assembly readAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(readAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Test.txt"));`

Error:
System.Reflection.Assembly' does not contain a definition for 'GetExecutingAssembly'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read embedded resource text file][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314140/how-to-read-embedded-resource-text-file

Comment: @supergeek, what's the problem with `GetExecutingAssembly()`? Does it return `null`? Does it throw an exception? Does it spit in your Cheerios?

Comment: It says It can't find the reference though I'm definitely referencing System.Reflection.. it seems it might of been removed to work the way something like http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292 does

Comment: Strange, [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getexecutingassembly%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) say it's supported on Windows 8 Beta and Consumer Preview... Can you post the exact code that calls `GetExecutingAssembly()`?

Comment: Do you mean WinRT? Windows 8 is unlikely to be the issue here...

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I expect he means WinRT, not Windows 8

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi updated the first section with code. I thought it was strange too because the docs mentioned it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In **WinRT** the resources should be included in the package. You use `Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync` to read the resource.

The following post has some sample code:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/d4b327e3-a8f2-4d3c-8ed7-ba2ea953d0b9

Comment: Thanks :)
Protip for others: Search for WinRT instead of Windows 8 haha

Answer (score 2):

In AppStore libraries you can use following code:

```
Stream stream = this.GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(fileName);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed.  You can also find out the exact name to use for the file by seeing what's part of your assembly:(assuming you have the Assembly as shown above)  string[] names = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use ReadFileAsync() Method available in VS 2012.
Add the text file to your project and call the async method